# GWT filltext not working on iPad 3

Tags: java, ios, ipad, gwt, html5-canvas

I'm developing a GWT application to iPad 3 running iOS 5.1.1. . The problem is when I want to use the GWT `fillText()` method, it not seems to work. It draws the text but the width is not correct which I give to the method's maxWidth attribute. However it works on Chrome and Opera. I have also tried to use `strokeText()`, but this didn't work either. iOS 5.1.1. doesn't support fillText()? Is there any solution to solve this problem?

UPDATE:

So far I have tried a w3schools editor webpage on the iPad 3 and the fillText's max width doesn't work.

UPDATE2:

I've tested the fillText method on Safari 5.1.7 browser on Windows 7 and it doesn't work well too. It's getting scarier..